# Special smooth non-analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, analytic-functions

Is there a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0 
$  $\forall x\leq 0$, $f(x)=1 $  $\forall x\geq 1$, and it is mononically increasing?

Comment: Could you please add more context to your question? For instance, do you know how to build a non-negative smooth function with compact support?

Comment: A non negative smooth function with compact support is $e^{-1/x+1/(x-1)}$ in $[0,1]$

Comment: Okay. If $f$ is continuous, you should know the derivative of $F(s):=\int_0^s f$. If $f$ is smooth, then $F$ is even better than only differentiable. Can you put this together with what I said before, and see if this helps somehow?

Comment: Also, I've noticed that you asked 7 questions on this site, none of them with accepted answer, and none of them with contextualization. Please, consider taking a quick look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/59234) for the future. This will helps us narrow down what you know or don't know, among other things. Also, consider accepting the answers that were helpful to you somehow.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I am new to this website, I will surely remember your points in future. And you answered my question, the context was very important.

Comment: I understand. I appreciate your responsiveness! : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $g=0$ for $x\le 0,$ $g>0$ for $0<x<1,$ and $g=0, x\ge 1.$ Let $c = \int_{\mathbb R} g.$ Then

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{c}\int_{-\infty}^x g(t)\,dt$$

does what you want

Answer (score 1):

Let$$g(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\leqslant0\\e^{-1/x}&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$which is smooth. Now, define $f(x)$ as$$\frac{g(t)}{g(t)+g(1-t)}$$and you'll have the function that you're after.

Comment: I want an infinitely differentiable function(smooth function)

Comment: @SaurabhPurohit Please tell me what you think about my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda$ is a non-negative (and not identically zero) smooth function with support in $[0,1]$, then the function
$$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
given by
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda} \cdot\int_{0}^x \lambda$$
satisfies what you want. Indeed, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda}\cdot \lambda(x)  \geq 0$, and thus $f$ is monotonically increasing. It is then easy to check that $f$ satisfies all other requirements.